# How to change user English number to Persian/Arabic instantly after user writes in the input tag?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

i'm using Vuejs and I want to prevent input tag from showing user's characters and replace it with my own characters(which is some numbers).

I have already used @onchange and Watch and also getters and setters in computed. the problem is the character instantly appears on input and then changes to what i want.

```
 <input v-model="phonenumber"  id="downloadlink" v- 
    on:keydown="sendDownloadLink"  placeholder=""
    maxlength="11" autocomplete="off"
    >
```

and in methods:

```
sendDownloadLink(e){
          this.phonenumber = this.toPersianNum(this.phonenumber);
         }
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Can you share reproducible example ?

Comment: i've edited and and add some codes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems here that are difficult to overcome:

1. Only the `input` event is a reliable. Keyboard events won't necessarily fire if the value changes by copy/paste or drag/drop.
2. The `input` event fires after the input has been updated, so the characters the user types will be seen, albeit briefly, until the event listener can change them.
3. If the user changes characters in the middle of the value the position of the text cursor will jump to the end when updating the value to use the new numerals.

One way this could be approached is by using a font that shows the desired numerals for the characters 0 to 9. This would dodge most of the difficulties.

The code below attempts a JavaScript solution instead. It uses the `input` event as a catch-all. To try to prevent the wrong characters showing temporarily it cancels the `keypress` event and makes the necessary changes to the value itself. In all cases it tries to preserve the position of the text cursor using `setSelectionRange`.

This is not a particularly good demonstration of 'correct' Vue usage but I'm not sure the functionality can be achieved without resorting to direct DOM manipulation.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',

  data() {
    return {
      phoneNumber: ''
    }
  },

  methods: {
    getInputValue() {
      const input = this.$refs.input
      const value = input.value
      const start = input.selectionStart
      const end = input.selectionEnd

      return [
        value.slice(0, start),   // before selection
        value.slice(start, end), // selection
        value.slice(end)         // after selection
      ]
    },

    onInput() {
      this.setInputValue(...this.getInputValue().map(this.toArabicNumerals))
    },

    onKeyPress(ev) {
      ev.preventDefault()

      const [before, , after] = this.getInputValue()
      const keyValue = this.toArabicNumerals(ev.key)

      this.setInputValue(before + keyValue, '', after)
    },

    setInputValue(before, selection, after) {
      const input = this.$refs.input
      const start = before.length
      const end = start + selection.length

      this.phoneNumber = input.value = before + selection + after

      input.setSelectionRange(start, end)
    },

    toArabicNumerals(str) {
      return str.split('').map(chr => {
        if ('0' <= chr && chr <= '9') {
          return String.fromCharCode(+chr + 1632)
        }

        if ('\u0660' <= chr && chr <= '\u0669') {
          return chr
        }

        return ''
      }).join('')
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input
    ref="input"
    :value="phoneNumber"
    @input="onInput"
    @keypress="onKeyPress"
  >
</div>
```

You may find that you can remove the `onKeyPress` listener altogether. On the hardware I had available for testing it didn't seem to make any difference but that might not be true for slower machines. The method `setInputValue` updates the `<input>` element's value directly and it may be that that is sufficient to get the desired results without the need for `onKeyPress`.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it with Vue **custom directives**.

First, you must use this function to convert English digits to Persian digits.

```js
// utilities/toPersianDigit.js
export function toPersianDigit (value) {
    return value?.toString().replace(/\d/g, x => String.fromCharCode(x.charCodeAt(0) + 1728))
}
```

Second, use this custom directive. It is common to globally register custom directives at the app level to make them usable in all components.

```js
import { toPersianDigit } from '~/utilities/toPersianDigit'

const app = createApp({})

app.directive('persian-digit', {
   update(el, binding) {
    const intactValue = el.value
    let modifiedValue = toPersianDigit(intactValue) // convert English digits to Persian digits

    // lets Vue knows we have changed the value
    if (modifiedValue !== intactValue) {
      el.value = modifiedValue
      el.dispatchEvent(new Event('input', { bubbles: true }))
    }
  }
})
```

Now you can use the persian-digit directive in all components like this

```html
<input
    v-model="phoneNumber"
    v-persian-digit
    maxlength="11"
/>
```